# Converting an NSString result from SQLite into a formatted NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I know that it sounds incessantly familiar, but most of the suggested solutions on SO have not worked for me for some strange reason.

I have a **date string returned from an SQLite query** as an NSString in this format:

```
2019-06-10 13:45:33
```

However, when any of the suggested date formatter solutions are applied, **with or without timezone localisation**, I keep getting such a result:

```
Mon Jun 10 13:45:33 2019
```

This is one of the routines I've tried, among many others:

```
NSString * dateString = @"2019-06-10 13:45:33";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
//[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
//[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

// dateFromString > Mon Jun 10 13:45:33 2019
```

Could I be doing something wrong or is there some missing step in the conversion?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I could guess that you wanted another output format, if it is the case then you could try code like this:

```
NSString * dateString = @"2019-06-10 13:45:33";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
//[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
//[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSDateFormatter *printDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
printDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateIntervalFormatterMediumStyle;
printDateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateIntervalFormatterMediumStyle;

NSLog(@"%@", [printDateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
```

The result will be:

```
10 Jun 2019 at 13:45:33
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a different formatter to format the string from the date. For example:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter=[[NSDateFormatter]alloc]init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
NSString * formattedDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

setDateFormat is for inputting date strings and getting NSDates.

dateStyle and timeStyle is for formatting dateStrings from NSDates.